# iOS, sorting through two arrays with different counts simultaneously

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsarray, enumeration

I am getting an NSRangeException error when test an array's contents (arrayTwo) inside another array enumeration (arrayOne), if arrayTwo does not have a count equal or greater to arrayOne. What is the most efficient way to do this? Basically I want to grab the object from arrayTwo if it exists, else if there is no object there, just ignore the operation.

```
int i = 0;
for (Class *arrayOneObject in arrayOne) {
    if (arrayTwo[i]!= NULL) {
        NSLog(@"array two object found");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Edit: According to Hot Lick's suggestion, I did the following, works fine.

```
int i = 0;
for (Class *arrayOneObject in arrayOne) {
    if (arrayTwo.count > i) {
        NSLog(@"array two object found");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Uh, maybe you should test the length of arrayTwo:  `arrayTwo.count > i`

Comment: Objective-C collection classes cannot contain `nil` object pointers; so that won't work.  If it's sorting you want then combine the arrays into a single array prior to sorting.

Comment: Normally you'd use a double-headed compare on sorted arrays, but I don't know that you can sort an array of Classes and get something reproducible.

Comment: And to accomplish the above test you could simply compare the length of the two arrays, since that's all you're actually checking.

Comment: Edit the question with more specifics. You have two arrays already ordered. You want the last item which is in common? The first? The common array?